# Focused Inbox Disappeared! (Microsoft Outlook of Mac)

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook

I'm using Outlook for Mac version 16.27 (19071500) on MacOS Mojave 10.14.4. I'm on a corporate Exchange / Office 365 account.

I rely heavily on the Focused Inbox to separate important messages from noise. This morning after restarting my computer, Focused Inbox is gone!

According to the help menu, I should be able to enable Focused Inbox by selecting an option in the ribbon.

[image: Outlook for Mac Help shows a Focused Inbox button]

When I look at my ribbon, the option to enable Focused Inbox is missing.

[image: screenshot of my ribbon]

And as far as I can tell, there's no way to customize the ribbon on a Mac and add the missing option.

I've tried selecting and deselecting the "Hide On My Computer" folders in preferences, and that didn't change anything. (It's currently selected.)

How can I get my beloved Focused Inbox back?

Comment: (1) Try to change preferences to hide folders "On my computer". (2) Do you use an Office 365 subscription with an outlook.com e-mail address (because this doesn't work on Mac)?

Comment: Thanks! It's a corporate account and I've had Focused Inbox for months. "Hide On My Computer folders" is checked. I tried turning it off an on again and that didn't help. Updated the answer with this info.

Comment: Try to keep "Hide On My Computer folders" turned off.

Comment: Okay, I turned it off again. Restarted Outlook while it was turned off. Looked at all three inboxes (On My Computer, email@company.com, and "All Accounts"). Focused Inbox is still not there and not available in the ribbon.

Comment: What has changed on your computer? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc Sorry, I thought it pinged you automatically when you're the only other person in the conversation. I figured out what happened. Outlook was somehow deactivated. See my answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I was having this issue recently and was driving me crazy. Like Patrick, I rely on the Focused Inbox. For me it was actually turning *on* "Hide On My Computer Folders" and suddenly Focused Inbox came back. I'm not sure how that got changed.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook was offline. There's a message in the bottom-right corner of the window that either says "Connected to your@email.com" or "Outlook is Offline".

When I hit Send/Receive, I was prompted to activate Outlook. Since the license is part of a corporate subscription, that was just matter of entering my password to log in.

Once I did that, the Focused Inbox and ribbon button came back. I'm not sure if it was activating the software or connecting to the server that made the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility... in the left column section, you may have been looking at the Inbox under "All Accounts" rather than under your "Office365" account (usually listed as your email address). You'll notice that if you click between the two inboxes, your Focused Inbox will disappear/reappear.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings for Outlook: Reading and in the middle of the options, look for Focused Inbox: "sort messages into Focused and Other" and check it.